# Mozilla Thunderbird

Tags: boot

Mozilla Thunderbird does not want to load in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS/ I have cleared all cookies.
 What is the easiest way to get Thunderbird working again ?I am new to Ubuntu.
Thank you

Comment: Start it from a Terminal and copy/paste the output

Comment: Can you open Thunderbird or is the problem that you can open it but you can't get mail?

Comment: Why the 'boot' tag?